# WhatsApp Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

is there any Plugin that enables us to chat on WhatsApp inside the website not by going **web.whatsapp.com.**
I checked many plugins that allow chatting but it will redirect us to WhatsApp website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such thing available, as WhatsApp allows you to interact by going web.whatsapp.com only.

***You can use plugins like*** **[WP Social Chat](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-whatsapp-chat/)** :

WhatsApp Chat also allows you to include a box to show some contact information and a personalized message. This box can be activated through the Box tab inside the WhatsApp chat section and here you can define the header and footer message, contact name, phone, work, and avatar

***WhatsApp Chat Features***

- WhatsApp button
- WhatsApp contact box
- WhatsApp button and box colors
- Add custom icon in the WhatsApp button
- Two button layouts
- Hide the button based on post types and taxonomies
- Add rounded or square borders
- Vertical and horizontal position
- Custom button text
- Custom user message

Answer (score 0):

I think wp-phone-message is what you are looking for. It gives the possibility to render a form through a shortcode.